# MySQL Query to Subtract 1st column of 1st row with 2nd column of 2nd row

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a Mysql Code, and I have no clue how to solve this. I have two columns with time value on which I've ordered by desc in Mysql Query result.

I need to find out the differences between the 2nd row StateEndTime and the 1st-row StateStarTtime nd so on and display this in a new row/column. The final table should look like this :

```
ID          Type         StateStarTtime    StateEndTime   Min Difference

xxx         YYY          03:57             03:59          00:02
xxx         ZZZ          03:53             03:55          00:04
xxx         ZZZ          03:46             03:49
```

Comment: So, Each row has StateStartTime and StateEndTime and you need for every row a calculated column which is   StateStartTime of that row -  StateEndTime of next row ?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: That's the third time you have asked this question in the last 2 days. If you are not getting answers then it's a bad question. You could improve this question by providing sample data and expected output as text in the question. I suspect you may need to generate a row number using row number simulation (prior to version 8) or row_number window function (version 8 and above) as a starting point.

Comment: to add to @P.Salmon 's comment about the row_number part for older MySQL versions you can use MySQL user variables or co-related queries with `COUNT(*)` to simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` (or `DENSE_RANK()` for that matter)... Pretty sure this question has a few duplications on stackoverflow how to look to the last or next record (`LAG()` and `LEAD()` and how to simulate those) in MySQL

Comment: I have tried to solve this problem in PHP HTML and now in MySQL, I have provided code and example in all of my Question. i thought the reason I'm not getting an answer is because my question is not reaching the right people.

Comment: the expected result looks wierd why does the first record have a difference of 2 seconds? if seams the first record has the column difference between StateStarTtime  - StateStarTtime  from the same record instead of a calculation to the next record..

Comment: I looked at your previous posts and there is no source data that I can see only as in this question 'here's the result of a query' that need more done to it.

Comment: @P.Salmon is right ideally you should provide example data and expected result. Yatendra singh ranawat ideally you should take a look into [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't know how to make my question more appealing but the link provided by Raymond help me understand thank you.

Comment: As of now, you have showed us **expected results**, which is fine. But to *make your question more appealing*, as explained above, you would need to provide the corresponding **sample data**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is an auto increment column, this can be achieved in MySQL by self join technique:

```
 SELECT 
  t1.ID,
  t1.Type,
  t1.StateStartTime,
  t1.StateEndTime
  (t1.StateStartTime - t2.StateEndTime) AS Min_Diff
 FROM
 Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
 Table1 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id + 1
```

Comment: even if it was an auto increment this wouldn't be a great solution, if a row was deleted it could all get thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified in a MYSQL 8 with CTE and or the ROW_NUM function but this will work to get the solution you are after in most versions.

I've also casted your times as in the example they arent in the correct format, this may not be the case in your actual data.

```
SET @row_number_a = 0;
SET @row_number_b = -1;

SELECT a.id, a.type, a.start, a.end, TIMEDIFF(CAST(a.start AS TIME), CAST(b.end AS TIME)) AS DIFF  
FROM
(SELECT (@row_number_a:=@row_number_a + 1) AS num, id, type, start, end
FROM tbl) a

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT (@row_number_b:=@row_number_b + 1) AS num, id, type, start, end
FROM tbl
) b
ON a.num = b.num
```

Result:

```
"id"    "type"  "start" "end"   "DIFF"
"xxx"   "YYY"   "03:57" "03:59" "00:02:00"
"xxx"   "ZZZ"   "03:53" "03:55" "00:04:00"
"xxx"   "ZZZ"   "03:46" "03:49" \N
```

Comment: I have MySQL version 10.1.36-MariaDB

Comment: Not too sure with the mariadb -> mysql version comparability.

Comment: @yatendrasinghranawat how is it not showing the correct results, i replicated you example and your output and that is the sql that did it? you may need to edit your question

Comment: the time difference it showing is not correct screenshot for your reference https://ibb.co/vwZ3wff
https://ibb.co/NCKCtsg
https://ibb.co/61YBjQP

Comment: your question doesnt mention anything about splitting it by emp.id. show your actual schema your working with and exactly what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you trying to do?

```
  mysql_query("SELECT *, `StateEndTime`-`StateStarTtime` AS `Min Difference` 
  FROM `TableName`");
```

Comment: Each row has StateStartTime and StateEndTime and I need for every row a calculated column which is StateStartTime of that row - StateEndTime of next row